# iMessage game - send hidden value

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

I follow [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-imessage-app-in-ios-10--cms-26870) to learn iMessage app.
Everything seems ok.
However, I want to develop a game like `BattleShip` kind of game.
That means I need to send in the value which is hidden from the other player. 
How can I do that?

Comment: [Hide this in the `url`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessage/1649739-url)? I haven't used iMessage app though.

Comment: You are right. I check a few more tutorial it seems like that is the only way. Can you post it as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the hidden parameters as part of the [URL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessage/1649739-url), like

```
message.url = URL(string: "http://battleship.example.com/?state=AAAAAA==")!
```

Note that the URL cannot be more than 5000 characters long (i.e. at most about 3.5 KiB of data after base-64.)

You may want to checkout the tutorial on https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios-10-day-by-day-day-1-messages.

To prevent cheaters from easily modifying the URL parameters, you might want to encrypt and/or sign the URL parameters.